# Sonarqube is not showing code coverage after running

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I'm running sonarqube with maven.

I have installed it using following [way](https://github.com/usnistgov/iheos-toolkit2/wiki/Installing-Sonarqube). 
Using `brew`, I installed `mysql` and `sonar`.

When I run I get 7 critical bugs but the code coverage for 88 tests is zero
[image: Sonarqube analysis]

When I run it with IntelliJ's tools, I get the following results. (not zero!)
[image: IntelliJ analysis]

This is when I check Jacoco results directly. In `$base_direc/target/jacoco/index.html`
[image: Jacoco results]

The same code when run with sonar-scanner[image: sonar-scanner]

---

This is my maven configuration
[image: maven configuration]

My `~/.m2/settings.xml`
[image: settings-pic1]
[image: settings-pic2]

---

Edit 1:
I have found this in logs. [image: Db not supported]

---

Edit2:
I have edited `~/.m2/settings.xml` 
added

```
<properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

Edited `/usr/local/Cellar/sonarqube/6.3.1/libexec/conf/sonar.properties`
added `sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/`

Edited `/usr/local/etc/sonar-scanner.properties` added - `sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/`

Ran the application in all above ways and the results were same, i.e, I could see Jacoco results but not in sonar.

---

Is it possible that if bugs are found sonar refuses to do code coverage?!

Comment: Anything relevant-seeming in your analysis log? If so, please [edit] your question to include that as well.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I have found something and edited the question. Please check, is that helpful

Comment: is there anything related to the processing of the coverage reports?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the solution -

The maven plugin I have included has configuration of Jacoco's destfile and datafile as `${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec`

but by default sonar reads at `${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec`. I changed the default at http://localhost:9000/settings?category=java

---

Ref: [Sonar Code Coverage](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project)

---

Couldn't find the working reference link. Here is aux link: [Baeldung Sonar and jacoco](https://www.baeldung.com/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage)

Comment: Reference link is dead

Comment: Life saver! Thank you for posting.

Comment: Did you re-run sonarqube for the changes to take effect??

Comment: I don't actually remember, it was 4.5 years ago. Please check the documentation. I tried looking for it, couldn't find.

Answer (score 5):

I've resolved this by using the following steps:

### 1.To begin, I've add configuration in our pom.xml.

```
<properties>
  <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
  <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
  <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>
```

---

### 2.In sonarqube properties file added the below part.

```
sonar.projectName=${JOB_NAME}
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.binaries=target/classes
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.verbose=true
```

---

Comment: I think the `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. I wasted about 2 days at work trying to find this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I will help you to resolve that. Here 1st thing is to walk through your pom file.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco-ut.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPaths>target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPaths>
</properties>
```

In pom file, you used **jacoco-ut.exec** you have to use below properties on your 
execute SonarQube Scanner in Jenkins

```
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco-ut.exec
```

**Keep in your mind about jacoco.exec in pom and property name of executing SonarQube Scanner in Jenkins**

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was:
Reports are getting generated at pre-package phase. Now we updated Pull Request maven phase.
`mvn -B clean test` to  `mvn -B clean package`.

Also, latest SONAR prefers XML report. You can specify path in maven pom via:
`<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>`

and in sonar project properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=my-project
sonar.projectName=my-project

sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.exclusions=**/beans/*,**/config/*,**/constants/*,**/dtos/**,**/entity/*,**/exceptions/*,**/insights/*,**/App.java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
```